# Graphql get array of objects with specific fields

Tags: graphql

## Tech Stack

1. typescript
2. typeORM
3. graphql (with apollo)
4. react
5. redux & redux-toolkit
6. MySQL

## Case 1

```
query {
    teamInfo([1, 2]) {
        team,
        teamName,
        teamMemberCount
    }
}
```

return =>

```
[
    {
        team: 1,
        teamName: "A",
        teamMemberCount: 3
    },
    {
        team: 2,
        teamName: "B",
        teamMemberCount: 7
    }
]
```

## Case 2

```
query {
    teamInfo([3, 4]) {
        team,
        slogun
    }
}
```

return =>

```
[
    {
        team: 3,
        slogun: "GOGO!"
    },
    {
        team: 4,
        slogun: "HELLO!"
    },
]
```

How to design query type and resolver in this case ?

Check please :D

Answer (score 0):

I found answer by myself.

This is possible. Graphql is really COOL !

`resolver.ts` file.

```
teamInfo: async (parent, args, context: ~~, info) => {
  const { teams } = args;
  ~~
  ~~
  return [
    {
      team: ~,
      teamName: ~,
      teamMemberCount: ~,
      slogun: ~
    },
    {
      team: ~,
      teamName: ~,
      teamMemberCount: ~,
      slogun: ~
    },
    {
      team: ~,
      teamName: ~,
      teamMemberCount: ~,
      slogun: ~
    },
    {
      team: ~,
      teamName: ~,
      teamMemberCount: ~,
      slogun: ~
    },
    {
      team: ~,
      teamName: ~,
      teamMemberCount: ~,
      slogun: ~
    },
  ]
}
```